# Chat Markdown with URL glitchy with underscores

Tags: bug, chat, markdown

I was trying to post `http://craphound.com/overclocked/Cory_Doctorow_-_Overclocked_-_When_Sysadmins_Ruled_the_Earth.html` as a link in the chat room. When it rendered, it first showed:

[craphound.com/overclocked/](http://craphound.com/overclocked/)…Overclocked-_When_Sysadmins_Ru‌​led_the_Earth.html

Then, I tried `[Read this](http://craphound.com/overclocked/…Overclocked-_When_Sysadmins_Ru‌​led_the_Earth.html)`, and got a URL reading:

`http://craphound.com/overclocked/Cory_Doctorow_-iOverclocked/i-_When_Sysadmins_Ruled_the_Earth.html`

I thing there's an issue with the markdown...

[Bob](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/35822/bob) found a way to post it:

[test](http://craphound.com/overclocked/Cory_Doctorow_%2D_Overclocked_%2D_When_Sysadmins_Ruled_the_Earth.html)

Using the URL Encoding characters, assuming it is actually the `%2D`. I feel this should get fixed though, as not everyone will know the URL Encoding versions of their URLs.

Comment: At least the `[link](http://like-this)` version works now.